# Uploading a folder to AWS CodeCommit repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

Can we upload a folder containing various code files from our local system to AWS CodeCommit.? If yes, then what are the steps to follow.?

Comment: Hey Jeet, Welcome at StackOverflow. If I understand correctly you are looking for something like this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/getting-started-cc.html#getting-started-cc-add

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to upload an entire folder through the UI. I think this the easiest way with an existing git repository, is as follows:

```
SCHEME="codecommit::${REGION}"
aws sts get-caller-identity # requires AWS credentials, with authorization
pip install git-remote-codecommit # using HTTPS GRC
git push -u ${SCHEME}://${TARGET_REPO} HEAD:refs/heads/master
```